# Arduino sketch- How to add Time Stamp for outgoing MQTT

Tags: esp8266, time

I'm writing a sketch in order to upload to a Sonoff device ( Remote relay, based ESP8266 ).

All is working great, but I wish my MQTT pubs to contain following format:

`[ DATE & TIME ] msg`

ESP8266 is connected to the internet.
I;m looking for a way doing it (including periodic time updates ) without running all 1MB memory, meaning: a code that 
1) get time from external source (LAN or WAN )
2) update it every 24h
3) Lite code ?

Thanks

Comment: please ask a specific question

Comment: updated, tough it seemed straight foreward

Comment: look into NTC, i think there's a built-in example, if not it's a very common lib with examples once added in the manager.

Comment: @dandavis You mean NTP surely...

Comment: @Majenko: good eye, that's what i meant, NTP. network time prototcol.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the ESP8266WiFi "[NTPClient](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/examples/NTPClient/NTPClient.ino)" example.  That will teach you how you can get the "Unix Epoch" time from the internet.

That value can be fed directly into [TimeLib](https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/Time) to keep track of the time for you (indeed, TimeLib includes an [NTP example for Arduino Ethernet](https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/Time/blob/master/examples/TimeNTP/TimeNTP.ino) that should help you get started).  Do that periodically (daily, hourly, whatever), and you have your time.  TimeLib can then give you the date and time as individual components (hours, minutes, etc), which you can then construct together (I'd use `snprintf`) to include in your MQTT message:

```
int len = strlen(message) + 25;
char mqttMessage[len];
snprintf(mqttMessage, len, "[%04d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d] %s",
    year(), month(), day(), hour(), minute(), second(), message);

mqttMessage => "[2018/08/11 20:36:24] foo"
```